# How to get price difference from same table in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have following table

```
slno date productid companyid price
88 2017-05-17 1 1 65.27 
87 2017-05-17 1 2 72.94
86 2017-05-17 1 3 73.13
85 2017-05-17 2 1 73.73
84 2017-05-17 2 2 67.71
83 2017-05-16 1 1 65.40 
82 2017-05-16 1 2 72.49
81 2017-05-16 2 1 73.31
80 2017-05-16 2 2 67.17
```

Now I want price of product 1 for 2017-05-17 and difference of price from yesterday for same company id.

e.g:

```
getPrice( productid = 1, date='2017-05-17')
and this should return :
companyid , productid , date, price, difference from yesterday:
1, 1,'2017-05-17', 65.27, -0.13
2, 1,'2017-05-17', 72.94, 0.45
```

...

```
or it should return:
companyid , productid , date, price, yesterday price:
1, 1,'2017-05-17', 65.27, 65.40
2, 1,'2017-05-17', 72.94, 72.49
```

...

How to get this in PHP SQL?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I need SQL for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing this with php, because php can tell you yesterdays and today date. So get yesterdays and today date with php and use it to manipulate the sql query

so the query should look something like this

yesterdays Price:

```
select companyid, productid , date, price from table where productid='1' and date='$yesterday';
```

Today price

```
select companyid, productid , date, price from table where productid='1' and date='$today';
```

now you can get both values and subtract them with php to get the difference